# creating a timer using a constructor not updating

Tags: javascript, canvas

The issue I am having is that I set a defined seconds through each constructor but it won't update every time the value is decreased, it stays at the parameter value, like 360. When I print seconds to the console.log() it is stuck at 360 for some odd reason. Anyone know a way to get it so that I can have multiple constructors and update the seconds for each constructor? so like

```
setInterval(function(){renderTime("drag",0,0,drag,6,360)}, 1000);
setInterval(function(){renderTime("cool",0,0,cool,3,180)}, 1000);
```

So to sum it up, the seconds parameter is not updating every second with seconds--; it is staying at whatever it is set at originally, like 360 or 180.
So instead of going 360,359,358,357; it goes 360,360,360,360.

```
function renderTime(name,x,y,img,minute,seconds) {
seconds--;
console.log(seconds);
var canvas = document.getElementById(name);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Time
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillText(seconds, (canvas.width/2)-8, height/2+80);

}

setInterval(function(){renderTime("drag",0,0,drag,6,360)}, 1000);
```

Comment: In your code the `setInterval` has a static number as parameters for the seconds instead of using the `seconds` variable. Should be more `setInterval(function(){renderTime("drag",0,0,drag,6,seconds)}, 1000);` where `seconds` was set as 360 previously.

Answer (score 0):

your first setInterval function will run the following function every 1000 milliseconds:

```
renderTime("drag",0,0,drag,6,360);
```

Inside the function, the variable `seconds`, which is local within the function, will be reduced by 1 but the next second the function will be called with new, fresh variables.

The solution is to set a global variable outside any function:

```
var seconds = 360;
```

And also REMOVE the last argument of your function, like this:

```
function renderTime(name,x,y,img,minute) {
seconds--;
console.log(seconds);
var canvas = document.getElementById(name);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Time
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillText(seconds, (canvas.width/2)-8, height/2+80);

}
```

And this is how your call to the function will look.

```
setInterval(function(){renderTime("drag",0,0,drag,6)}, 1000);
```

**Take note** that if you're starting two `setInterval()` both calling the same function, both of these functions will reduce the variable `seconds` by one each second so essentially, the variable will be reduced twice as fast.